# MySQL: How to select multiple tables (No join) ? (See example)

Tags: mysql

How to select multiple table (combine table: no join, because all field are the same)?

I have 2 tables:
+Table A

```
id | name | description | time
1     A        AA          7:01
2     B        BB          7:03
```

+Table B

```
id | name | description | time
1     C        CC          7:02
2     D        DD          7:04
```

I want to result:

Result: (ORDER BY time)

```
id | name | description | time
1     A        AA          7:01
1     C        CC          7:02
2     B        BB          7:03
2     D        DD          7:04
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL`

```
select  *
from    (
            select * from TableA
            union all
            select * from TableB
        ) t1
order by time
```

If you can have duplicates and want to avoid them, just switch from `UNION ALL` to `UNION`

Comment: Error: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 1):

use `Union all`

```
select id, name, description, time from tableA
Union all
select id, name, description, time from tableB
order by time
```